# How to select all the rows with 0

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataset where I have some 0 values in it. I want to print all the rows having 0.

[image: Dataset]

I was able to print a single column, but can't find a way to print all the columns.

[image: Single Column]

I am able to print like this, which is printing the 0 but I don't want these Nan just 0's.

[image: With NaN]

Output what I am expecting:
[Output needs to be printed:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqcYc.png)
Thanks!

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Comment: `df[df.eq(0).any(1)]`

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Your example prints all the columns.

Comment: @Barmar - I think OP wants to get the entire row if *any* of the columns has a 0 value. But agreed the question isn't framed clearly.

Comment: "print all the columns" should be "test all the columns"

Comment: Also not sure what "but I don't want these Nan just 0's" means

Comment: My apologies if it's not framed correctly. Like the dataset has some values in the columns and 0's as well. So I want to print all the columns having 0 but there shouldn't be any other values displayed. If you check the last image where the pregnancy column is showing all the values 0 though there are other values in that column as well. I want the same result for the entire data frame. Want to print all the columns where the column value is 0. I hope this explains well. @Barmar